# the exact meaning of 0byte assembly code line

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to analyze a generated assembly code and i don't know the meaning of this line:

**

> .0byte        .L99

**

Any ideas ?!

Comment: Have you checked the manual of your assembler (you didn't say which one it is)?

Comment: .L could stand for lable or line number. .0byte probably is a placeholder not allocating any bytes?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a typo for `.8byte`, which is a GAS directive.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/8byte.html

Comment: @Sebastian `.L99` looks like GCC output.  It auto-numbers labels within the asm for a compilation unit as `.L0` and counting up from there.  (And `.LC0` and up for constants.)  So if it's actually `.8byte .L99`, it's probably part of a jump table (for a `switch` maybe) on some ISA with 64-bit code pointers.  But not x86-64, GCC prefers `.quad` there. (https://godbolt.org/z/qrWY8Ebz8)